# Difference between hybrid and resistive RF power splitters, and Frequency Response?

Tags: rf, measurement

I am new into RF measurements, and have got a couple of questions regarding power splitters (hopefully common for all the models that exist in the market).

1. What's the difference between resistive and hybrid RF power splitters?
2. Does resistive RF power splitter has 6 dB power loss?
3. And hybrid RF power splitter has 3 dB power loss?
4. Do they have a fairly broadband/wideband support? I mean how does there frequency response looks like?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:
 5. Do Hybrid splitters have a better isolation between two unwanted paths compared to resistive splitter? (I think it's true, isn't it?)

Comment: Both resistive and 'hybrid' splitters come in various types. Either you have to be more specific about which type you want to compare, or the question is too broad to be answered here. 

Also, a quick google should really get you started on these topics. I suggest doing some research, and then coming back with more specific questions about what it is you don't understand or need some clarifying on.

Comment: Microwaves101 have nice pages about RF couplers/splitters:
https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/couplers-and-splitters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resistive splitters are essentially voltage dividers, and as a result dissipate power. A two way equal resistive splitter will have an insertion loss of 6 dB - 3 dB for the split, and 3 dB absorbed. The main advantage of a resistive splitter is that it is not frequency dependent, so they can work over very wide bands, from DC to GHz. Other types of power splitters do not use resistors in the same way and hence have lower insertion loss. Hybrid couplers are one of these. Hybrid couplers take one input and produce two outputs that are 90 degrees out of phase. Equal split hybrid couplers have an insertion loss of 3 dB, with little additional loss over the split. Hybrid couplers are narrow band devices and only operate well over a narrow frequency range.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite useful information for me.

Comment: Also, one related question. Hybrid couplers have a better isolation between two unwanted paths compared to resistive splitter? Correct?

Comment: yes, the isolation can be a lot better.  But it is also frequency dependent, so it could have less isolation outside of the design frequency range.